# Win 10 link to Google Drive folder keeps getting replaced with .bat file

Tags: windows-10, google-drive

I have a link to my Google Drive folder on my desktop but for reasons I can't fathom it keeps getting replaced with the Drive launcher bat file

I create the link to the folder
[image]

Works as expected
[image]

Only to find it replaced later
[image]

This happens all the time and it is quite annoying... What on earth is this black magic bs? Could it be MS One Drive synced desktop or what might be causing this?

Comment: You could try to edit the permissions of the .lnk file and deny write/delete access to everyone. That should stop any process like Google Drive client (which you seem to have installed) from replacing it.

Comment: I have changed the name of the link and it seems fine now, still curious what caused it